# Confused by ROC curves and cutoffs in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have some data on study participants, the percent change in a biomarker, and their ultimate outcome. I'd like to use an ROC curve to find the best cutoff value for the biomarker for predicting the outcome, using the Youden method but get different answers from different packages and need to know where I'm going wrong.
To set up the dataset:

```
ID <- c(1:17)

PercentChange <- c(-85.5927051671732, -85.4849965108165,
-63.302752293578, -33.5509138381201, -75, -87.0988867059594,
-93.2523616734143, 65.2037617554859, -19.226393629124,
-44.7095435684647, -65.7342657342657, -43.7831467295227,
-37.0022539444027, 518.75, -77.1014492753623, 20.6572769953052,
-72.0742534301856)

Outcome <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(ID, PercentChange, Outcome)
```

For outcome, 1 is favorable and 0 is unfavorable.

Now with package pROC I did:

```
library(pROC)
roc <- roc(df$Outcome, df$PercentChange, auc= TRUE, plot = TRUE)
coords(roc, "b", ret="t", best.method="youden")
plot(roc, print.thres="best", print.thres.best.method="youden",main = "Percent change")
```

This gives me a reasonable curve and a cutoff (by the Youden index) of -44.246 that I verified has the correct sensitivity and specificity listed. The cutpoint seems a bit weird since its halfway between two of the actual values and not an actual value, but it works.

Then using OptimalCutpoints I tried

```
library(OptimalCutpoints)
optimal.cutpoint.Youden <- optimal.cutpoints(X = "PercentChange", status = "Outcome", tag.healthy = 1, methods = "Youden", data = df)
summary(optimal.cutpoint.Youden)
plot(optimal.cutpoint.Youden)
```

This gives me a different curve, and a different cutpoint of -43.783, which is one of the two points that pROC took the midpoint of. The sensitivity and specificity are also flipped from what I calculated using that cutpoint.

Lastly I tried the roc function from the Epi package

```
library(Epi)
ROC(form=Outcome~PercentChange, data=df, plot="ROC", PV=TRUE, MX=TRUE)
```

Which gave me a third completely different curve and says "24" at the cutpoint which doesn't make any sense. Can anyone help me figure this out? I'm not asking on the stats stackexchange cause they'd want to get into whether Youden is appropriate or not and not the technical application of these functions.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Why are different methods returning different cutpoints? Is there a reason to expect them to be identical? It's really now clear to me from your description how this is a programming question and not a statistical question. What exactly are you trying to figure out?

Comment: @MrFlick These three should all be applying the same general ROC/Youden method to my data but are giving me three separate answers. Which should I trust, and how did I get the others wrong?